# Cannot login to aurora Postgres after using a newly created user

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

Hi created a new user in aurora Postgres using the command

```
CREATE USER testuser WITH PASSWORD 'testuser'
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO testuser
```

When I try to connect to the db

```
psql -h <dburl> -p 5432 -U testuser dbname
```

And enter the password 'testuser' (without the apostrophes) in the prompt I get an error:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testuser"
```

Did I enter the correct commands to create a user in aurora Postgres?

Comment: Looking in the docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createuser.html the user needs to have login "privilege" so try dropping the user and add the user with this `CREATE USER testuser WITH PASSWORD 'testuser' LOGIN` instead

Comment: Also, you might want to check if your pg_hba.conf file is properly configured to accept connections - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: it worked with login. thank you.